# How to check value of all text box with two class name?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textbox with two class `"Remark Valid"`
I want to check if it is empty or not.  That is `val()=""`. How to check it I don't know. I have many textbox with two class.

I am using below code:

```
$("div.editorRow input").each(function () {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    //Doing tasks
  }
}
```

But I just want to check if `"Remark Valid"` textbox's `value is ""` or not. I have other textbox also inside the div.

**Note: It was Val before, but I updated it as per my code as Valid. So pls don't be angry...**

Comment: plz show us some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Get all the text-boxes first
var $text = $('div.editorRow input.Remark.Val');

// Loop through each of them
$text.each(function () {

    // Trim the value to remove the whitespace from the beginning & end.
    if ($.trim(this.value) == '') {
        // Textbox is empty
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to compare it with $(this)'s class. Show my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector:

```
if($(".Remark.Valid").val() == "") {
 //code
}
```

just make sure that there's no spaces between them because it would mean that you're selecting   `.Val` that is a child of `.Remark` and you wouldn't want that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that all three answers you've received so-far share the same class-referral issue (ie: they're all targetting the class names `"Remark"` and `"Val"` - which aren't the classes you've specified in your question.

The principle is correct though: jQuery selectors will allow you to target using [multiple-class selectors](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/): more than one class together (`.classone.classtwo`).

So, the answer you're looking for, assuming the two classes on your inputs are `"Remark"` and `"Valid"` is:

```
$('.Remark.Valid').val();
```

This will grab the value of all elements with both classes.

To check whether it is empty or not (as your question edit), you were really close.  Here's how I would do it:

```
$("div.editorRow input").each(function () {
    var remarkInput = $(this).find('.Remark.Valid');

    if($.trim(remarkInput.val()) == ''){
        // then your input is empty
    }
}
```

You could also achieve the same thing by measuring the length of the input's value which is (arguably) slightly quicker:

```
if(remarkInput.val().length <= 0){
    // then your input is empty
}
```

Comment: @JudeDuran I only mention it because it's interesting that three of you popped up with virtually-identical answers, at the same time, with the same error in it.. I did wonder if the question had been edited as well but appears not.